# Why do I have to handle the Exception when "declaring" mock? Mockit#when

Tags: java, junit, mocking, mockito

I use this construction:

```
try {
    Mockito.when(rules1.onEvent(Mockito.<OnEventArgs>any(), Mockito.<Response>any())).thenReturn(true);
} catch (MalformedEventException e) {
    Assert.fail();
}
```

For mocking this interface:

```
public interface Rules {
    boolean onEvent(OnEventArgs onEventArgs, Response response) throws MalformedEventException;
}
```

However, I don't understand why I have to catch the Exception when using Mockito#when in my test? The exception should never be thrown in the "declaration" of the mock, right? So why do I have to deal with it there? ...And how should I handle it? Assert.fail()?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Mockito builds a proxy which must fulfill the signatures of the methods of the mocked class. Thrown exceptions are part of this signature. You can omit the try/catches by declaring `throws Exception` for your test method.

The exception of the mocked object will normally be not thrown, of course. This is only possible if you use `thenCallRealMethod()`.

Answer (score 1):

You don't need to catch the exception:

```
import static org.mockito.Matchers.isA;
import static org.mockito.Mockito.when;

...

@Test
public void something() throws Exception {
  when(rules1.onEvent(isA(OnEventArgs.class), isA(Response.class)).thenReturn(true); 
  ...
}
```

If the test throws any exception, JUnit will report a failure.